# Drag and Drop ghost trailing on drop w/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am having this problem when I try to reorder elements by dragging them. The reorder works but the functionality of changing places  is not performing as desired. When you drag an element/image from a `position x` to `position y` it will change the position and it will stay there but on `drop handler` a "ghost" section it tries to go to the old position and the delete button on the overlay disappears.

[image]

I've provided a [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-images-uploading-demo-typescript-forked-35246w?file=/src/App.tsx:6587-6629).

This is the component throwing the error.
[image]

as oposed to
[image]

I tried adding more event handlers like :

```
onDragOver
onDragDrop
onDragStart
onDragEnter
onDragLeave
```

and tried to add some logic to metigate the transition of images, but nothing worked.

```
{imageList.map((image, index, isDragging) => (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className="image-item w-1/2 sm:w-40 h-36 sm:p-2 px-1 pt-2"
                  draggable
                  onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, index)}
                  onDragEnd={(e) => handleDragEnd(e)}
                  onDragEnter={(e) => handleDragEnter(e, index)}
                  onDragLeave={(e) => handleDragLeave(e)}
                  onDragOver={(e) => handleDragOver(e, index)}
                  onDrop={(e) => handleDrop(e, index)}
                >
                  <div
                    className={`border relative bg-white h-full transition duration-200 ease-in-out `}
                  >
                    {/* //!IMAGE */}
                    <span
                      className={` w-full h-full bg-center bg-contain bg-no-repeat `}
                      style={
                        {
                          // backgroundImage: `url(${image.dataURL})`
                        }
                      }
                    >
                      <img src={image.dataURL} width="200" alt="" />
                    </span>
                    {/* OVERLAY */}
                    <div className="z-10 overlay absolute w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center opacity-0 hover:opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-300 bg-black bg-opacity-50">
                      <div className="flex">
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          onClick={() => onImageRemove(index)}
                          title=""
                        >
                          <span className="w-5 h-5">
                            <button>delete</button>
                          </span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
```